# how to unzip file which zipped and encrypted with CipherInputStream and ZipInputStream

Tags: java, encryption

I have the following code and it's OK when creating an encrypted zip file with the given file, however, I could not open the generated zip file with unzip command and it complains invalid zip.

"The Unarchiver" could not unzip as well.

```
public void encrypt(String desKey, String zipFileName, String fileName) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFileName);

        SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(desKey.getBytes(), "DESede");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);

        InputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher);

        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(cipherInputStream);
        ZipEntry nextEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        inputStream = zipInputStream;
        if (nextEntry == null) {
            System.out.println("error");
            inputStream = null;
        }
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            } else if (fileInputStream != null) {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } else if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zipping a stream does not means that you create a zip file... If you want to create a zip file with a crypted file in it, you should create ZipEntry, add it to the ZipOutputStream and then push your encrypted data. You can have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html wich is a good starting point.

Comment: how can I read the encryted file in other language like ruby and python?

Comment: no idea... read the language documentation about encryption. But you must use an encryption algorithm that is implemented in both language